reshape dataframe by append two more rows after each row
I would like to reshape dataframe by insert two rows after each row. the rule is:

The first column use current row value.
The second row always use a fixed value, say 0.
The third row always use None.

Demo code:
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A',1],
    ['B',2],
    ['C',3],
    ['D',4]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','value'])
print(df)


output:
  name  value
0    A      1
1    B      2
2    C      3
3    D      4


Expected output:
  name  value
0    A      1
1    A      0
2    A      None
3    B      2
4    B      0
5    B      None
6    C      3
7    C      0
8    C      None
9    D      4
10   D      0
11   D      None



Another possible solution, which first maps each value of value column to a list of the wanted values and then explodes the dataframe by the value column:
df.assign(value = df['value'].map(lambda x: [x, 0, None])).explode('value')

Output:
  name value
0    A     1
0    A     0
0    A  None
1    B     2
1    B     0
1    B  None
2    C     3
2    C     0
2    C  None
3    D     4
3    D     0
3    D  None


out = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(value=0), df.assign(value=None)])
         .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
)


I see three options:
using concat with assign to change the values, and sort_values/sort_index to reorder the rows:
out = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(value=0), df.assign(value=None)])
         .sort_values(by='name', ignore_index=True)
      )

Or:
out = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(value=0), df.assign(value=None)])
         .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
      )

using repeat to duplicate the rows and groupby.cumcount/mask with a dictionary of positions to replace:
# define positions to replace
d = {1: 0, 2: None}

# repeat rows
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(max(d)+1)]
# replace specific positions by custom values
s = out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
out['value'] = out['value'].mask(s.isin(d), s.replace(d))

# cleanup index
out.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

using assign to create new columns and stack
out = (df
   .set_index('name')
   .assign(value2=0, value3=None)
   .stack(dropna=False)
   .droplevel(1).reset_index(name='value')
)

NB. this might not work with None in the future pandas 3.
Output:
   name value
0     A     1
1     A     0
2     A  None
3     B     2
4     B     0
5     B  None
6     C     3
7     C     0
8     C  None
9     D     4
10    D     0
11    D  None

